# Previous command output on mac OS X

Tags: bash, shell

I have below script. When I run each line in iTerm on MacOs, every command works. But if i save this as a shell script, it says "!! command not found". I have tried #!/bin/bash. But still it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
./ongoingShellScript.sh 
if !! | grep "errors: 0"
then
  echo Success
else
  echo Failure
fi
```

I could have done

```
if ./ongoingShellScript.sh | grep "errors: 0"
```

But in this case, output of ongoingShellScript won't be printed in realtime.

What am i doing here ?
Thank you in advance

GV

Comment: History expansion is not available in noninteractive shells. Moreover, `!!` doesn't refer to previous output -- it *runs the whole command over again*.

Answer (score 2):

`!!` doesn't refer to previous output -- it runs the whole command over again, and thus generates a *new* set of output. Moreover, the featureset it comes from -- called "history expansion" -- is an interactive extension turned off by default during script execution.

If you want to print status for the user while testing stdout for a string, the easy tool for the job is `grep`:

```
if ./ongoingShellScript.sh | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q "errors: 0"; then
  echo "Success" >&2
else
  echo "Failure" >&2
fi
```

...assuming that `errors: 0` comes at the end of output, and thus that it's acceptable for `tee` to exit as soon as `grep` has seen this string.

Comment: Can you explain what's `!!`?

Comment: @FrankAK, a legacy feature made irrelevant by modern `readline`-style interactive command-line editing, and thus best disabled. :) -- for a more serious explanation, [the HISTORY EXPANSION section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) is the go-to reference.

Comment: I have simple put `!!` in my terminal, seems it's just run a previous command again. That's what it does , right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does (as mentioned in the first sentence of the answer). There's also a robust featureset that allows running a modified version ("run the prior command, except replace foo with bar"), from back in the days when we didn't have interactive visual editing.

Comment: I have try your solution, and it's work! BTW, I got a new hack skill `!!`, You did a good job!

Comment: Is there any other hack skill like this `!!` ?

Comment: btw, putting `set +H` in your dotfiles will disable history expansion and thus make the interactive shell behave more like the interpreter as it works in scripts.

Comment: ...and yes, there are lots of other things history expansion does -- `!-2` to rerun whatever was two commands ago, for example; or `^foo^bar^` to rerun the last command with `foo` changed to `bar`. See the manual, previously linked, for a full list.

Comment: If i do if ./ongoingShellScript.sh | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q "errors: 0"; then ./ongoingShellScript.sh output goes to tee /dev/stderr and doesn't print  at realtime.

Comment: @Gaurav, `/dev/stderr` refers to the current process's stderr, which usually *is* the terminal by default, thus printed in real time. If you redirected stderr away from the terminal in a part of the script you aren't showing us, then change it to `/dev/tty`.

Comment: @Gaurav, ...anyhow, to prove that `tee /dev/stderr` streams content in real-time, run `{ echo one; sleep 10; echo two; sleep 10; echo three; } | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q three` -- you'll see the `one` print immediately.

Comment: Looks like it is not working on MacOS High Sierra. it outputs everything at the end.

Comment: Here is similar issue      https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407455/how-to-make-any-program-work-with-the-tee-command

Comment: @Gaurav, when you say "it outputs everything at the end", do you mean your program, or do you mean the example I gave above? If it's only your program and *not* the example above, then you'll need to provide a reproducer -- code someone else can run to see the problem themselves.

Comment: @Gaurav, presumably this is just a buffering issue -- fix the called software to line-buffer its output or leave it entirely unbuffered and you'll be fine -- but we can't tell you how to do that unless we know the details of the software at hand (including the implementation language; enabling unbuffered output is different between, say, Python and C). It obviously *isn't* just a native shell script, because output isn't buffered across multiple `echo`s or `printf`s in shell -- if it were, you could reproduce the problem with the `echo one; sleep 10; echo two` example above.